# How do I change the soap:address location in the WSDL for a service on karaf?

Tags: soap, wsdl, apache-camel, apache-karaf

We have a karaf/camel/jetty installation that we inherited when we inherited a few clients from another company.  I was able to take a copy of the original karaf install directory off the old server and get it up and running on our new servers with a lot of hair-pulling.  I'm a LAMP software engineer, but I'm really not familiar with Karaf.

The WSDL that the service answers with shows it's address like...

```
  <wsdl:service name="RtiService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:RtiServiceSoap" name="RtiServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://int.example.com:8080/b2c"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I have the DNS already setup, but we'd like to change the WSDL to...

```
  <wsdl:service name="RtiService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:RtiServiceSoap" name="RtiServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://karaf.example.com:8080/b2c"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

We have a situation where we can't use the current address because it's specific to the server, not the service, making it impossible to move the service from server to server.  Soap clients can't seem to connect if the address in the WSDL doesn't match the URL it's trying to use for the connection.

I have spent hours searching for a clear answer to what seems like a simple change, but have come up with solutions that didn't provide the desired result.

Additional Info:
Karaf 2.2.1
Jetty7 2.6.0
Camel 2.6.0

**Update**
It appears the jar files for the service(s) are in the /deploy folder.  I tried dropping my updated .wsdl file in that folder with the same name as it's jar file, restarted and tested, but no change.

Comment: How do you instantiate the CXF service?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find and answer your question.  What is CXF and how do I find out?  I'm running Karaf as a service on our CentOS box.  I can connect via bin/client, and have seen how to do features:list, etc.

Comment: The jar files that seem to define the service are in the /deploy folder.

Comment: You will have to look into the sources. The service can either be published using camel or cxf.

Comment: What's interesting is that I don't think we ever set that location.  The former server was a completely different URL.  I tried changing our /etc/hostname and our /etc/sysconfig/network but it had no effect, if was reading if from the environment.

Comment: What clients are you using? There are some old PHP SOAP clients that actively used the WSDL as a URL registry, which is not ideal. The practical approach is that the location is a hint and the server-side can configure an override and the client-side can configure the url directly.